# AWS S3, as an organizer see empty bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I am an owner of organizer in on my aws account. When I enter S3 I see one folder, which is empty. But its being billed 8$ per month, so smth should be there.

Is it possible that one account, of my organization uploaded there some stuff and I dont see it ?

Answer (score 1):

Does the bucket have versioning enabled? You should be able to see it in the bucket properties: Versioning: enabled. If so, when you are looking at the empty folder, at the top there is a switch "show versions", switch it on. Do you see some objects with hashes?
Try to delete them. Be careful, there are versions and "delete markers", you have to delete both in order to completely empty the bucket.

Another option: you are billed for requests and data transfers https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/?nc=sn&loc=4
If something is checking the bucket rapidly, it can generate some costs.

But most often the delete versions is the reason.

Comment: no its disabled, well actually billing is not a problem, problem is that I would like to see those files :) its important backup :(

Comment: Hm, hard to guess from the information given, but if they are not current nor previous versions, the costs can come from something else. If you go to detailed billing (billing explorer) - is it really from s3 storage cost? Can you split it by storage class? Can it be glacier?

Comment: yes I am sure from billing details, that its from S3.

Comment: so maybe this other user, created s3 folder but not gaved permisions to others ? is it possible that organization owner did not see it ?

Comment: you should get an error message when you don't have access to it. You can check that you have s3:ListBucket on the bucket or all the buckets.

Comment: sometimes, there is a resource accidentally created in a different region, but s3 buckets are global, so if all you see is one bucket which has versioning disabled and is empty it does not make any sense to be charged for s3 storage. The only thing which comes to my mind is that today I checked the pricing of the storage classes and some them have minimal payment period for example s3: glacier will charge you for 90 days minimum, and deep storage even 180. Not sure the split it across the months, I do not use it at the moment.

Comment: but is it possible, that user ( who is not available anymore ) has created s3 bucket, and filled up with some data, but set restricted read permissions there ? so I as an organizer can not see it ?